# Couldn't find Group with 'id'= Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this method in my groups controller that is looking for the `id` of the group that is passed in the params.

```
def set_group
  @group = Group.find(params[:id])
end
```

I have this route, and a couple others, that are looking for the `group_id` rather than the `id`. Since it is not finding the `group_id` it is throwing this error.

```
/accounts/:account_id/groups/:group_id/settings
```

> Couldn't find Group with 'id'=

How can I tell this variable to find the params of the `id` and or the `group_id`? I have listed all my routes for this particular instance below and half require the `id` and the other require the `group_id`.

```
/accounts/:account_id/groups/:group_id/add_map(.:format)  
/accounts/:account_id/groups/:group_id/add_map(.:format)  
/accounts/:account_id/groups/:group_id/maps(.:format)   
/accounts/:account_id/groups/:group_id/add(.:format)   
/accounts/:account_id/groups/:group_id/add(.:format) 
/accounts/:account_id/groups/:group_id/remove/:id(.:format) 
/accounts/:account_id/groups/:group_id/maps/:map_id/remove(.:format) 
/accounts/:account_id/groups/:group_id/settings(.:format)          
/accounts/:account_id/groups(.:format)                               
/accounts/:account_id/groups(.:format)                               
/accounts/:account_id/groups/new(.:format)                           
/accounts/:account_id/groups/:id(.:format)                           
/accounts/:account_id/groups/:id(.:format)                           
/accounts/:account_id/groups/:id(.:format)                           
/accounts/:account_id/groups/:id(.:format)
```

Would I just need a separate variable with the `group_id`?

Comment: Have you tried `@group = Group.find(params[:group_id] || params[:id])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look for one or the other in the `params` and use the first one you find, like:

```
def set_group
  id = params[:group_id] || params[:id]
  @group = Group.find(id)
end
```